# pause enpoint is not available

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I am using Finchley.SR1 with following cloud dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

I have enabled pause config like this
```

```
 endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true    
  pause:
    enabled: true
```

Still no pause and resume endpoint available is actuator like before

`{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator","templated":false},"archaius":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/archaius","templated":false},"auditevents":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/auditevents","templated":false},"beans":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/beans","templated":false},"health":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/health","templated":false},"conditions":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/conditions","templated":false},"configprops":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/configprops","templated":false},"env-toMatch":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/env/{toMatch}","templated":true},"env":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/env","templated":false},"info":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/info","templated":false},"loggers":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/loggers","templated":false},"loggers-name":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/loggers/{name}","templated":true},"heapdump":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/heapdump","templated":false},"threaddump":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/threaddump","templated":false},"metrics":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/metrics","templated":false},"metrics-requiredMetricName":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}","templated":true},"scheduledtasks":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/scheduledtasks","templated":false},"httptrace":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/httptrace","templated":false},"mappings":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/mappings","templated":false},"refresh":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/refresh","templated":false},"features":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/features","templated":false},"service-registry":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/service-registry","templated":false},"bindings-name":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/bindings/{name}","templated":true},"bindings":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/bindings","templated":false},"channels":{"href":"http://localhost:18182/actuator/channels","templated":false}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint configuration properties have been changed since Spring Boot 2.0.
To enable `/actuator/restart`, `/actuator/pause` and `/actuator/resume` you need to use `management.endpoint.restart.enabled=true`.
Also don't forget to include these endpoints in `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. :) Can you provide a sample for me to check?
I verified this before and I see following available web endpoints:
`
"restart": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/restart",
    "templated": false
},
"pause": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/pause",
    "templated": false
},
"resume": {
    "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/resume",
    "templated": false
}
`

Comment: yes it was my mistake i was writing endpoints in place of endpoints

Comment: Do you know the documentation for this? Where is this written?